# Why wasn't there a mug shot of Andy along with the story?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shawshank-redemption

In *The Shawshank Redemption*, upon Andy's escape and the discovery of his clothes and the pickaxe, why wasn't there a mug shot of him along with the newspaper story? It stands to reason that if a picture was included with the story, someone in the bank would probably have read the paper(s) and recognised him...

Comment: Andy escaped during the night and was visiting the banks the next morning.  The newspapers wouldn't have had the story yet.

Comment: The story is also set in a time when it would have been difficult to obtain those sort of photos quickly, i.e. in time to make print deadlines

Comment: Well, those sound like answers to me, not comments.

Answer (score 2):

### It'd not have been possible.

Andy escaped in the night and the guards and the warden came to know about this in the morning. They checked the cells at 6:30 in the morning.

From the novel,

> the cell doors in Cellblock 5 opened at 6:30 A.M.

And they started searching for him right away. Nobody had time to send the information in newspapers. In this short period, they couldn't have get it published.

**If I recall correctly, newspapers was already published by then. We can see a newspaper in the warden's hands when he was coming to his office.** (I will try to get an image later.)

From [the screenplay](http://www.screenwrite.in/Screenplays/Shawshank%20Redemption,%20The%20(1993.02.22).pdf),

> HAIG: WHAT THE F^%K!
>
> INT -- NORTON'S OFFICE -- MORNING (1966) 217
>
> **Norton is kicking back with the morning paper.** He notices ha
>    dingy his shoes are. He glances at the shoebox on the desk. 
>    kicks his shoes off, opens the box -- and gulls out Andy's o
>    grimy work shoes. He stares blankly. What the f&^k indeed.
>
> An ALARM STARTS BLARING throughout the prison. He looks up.
>
> EXT -- PRISON -- DAY (1966) 218
>
> Norton and Hadley stride across the grounds, ALARM BLARING.
>
> NORTON  I want every man on that cellblock  questioned! Start with
>   that friend  of his!
>
> HADLEY  who?
>
> INT -- CELLBLOCK FIVE -- RED'S CELL -- DAY (1966) 219
>
> Red watches as Norton storms up with an entourage of guards.
>
> NORTON  Him.
>
> Red's eyes widen. Guards yank him from his cell.

As suggested by Paulie_D, there might be a story regarding Andy's escape, but this newspaper was published next day and he has already taken the money and left the country.

Comment: How accurately reproduced is that screenplay? I would expect the final screenplay for a film to have less blatant typos and grammatical problems in it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist [Same script](http://nldslab.soe.ucsc.edu/charactercreator/film_corpus/film_2012xxxx/imsdb.com/Shawshank-Redemption,-The.html)

Answer (score 0):

> why wasn't there a mug shot of him along with the newspaper story? It stands to reason that if a picture was included with the story, someone in the bank would probably have read the paper(s) and recognised him...

I'm not sure which newspaper story you are referring to.

The only newspaper article I think we see **isn't about Andy's escape**, it's about murder and corruption at the prison.

[image]

Certainly, we see a picture of the clothes and axe being taken...

[image]

...but that's not the subject of the newspaper article.

It's possible that the story of the escape was *inside* the paper (or was in an earlier edition) and did feature Andy's mug shot (and the picture above) but, as was stated in the comments...no-one knew Andy had escaped until **after** he had visited the bank(s).